# Why to choose to work with a functional instead of a function?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Why to choose to work with a functional instead of a function?

Notice in a function you evaluate points and in functional you evaluate functions.

and why a linear functional is important in general ?

A functional $\phi(f)$ is linear if the domain of its existence together with the functions $f(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ contain the function $af(x)+b\psi(x)$ and if the equality  $\phi(af+b\psi)=a\phi(x)+b\phi(\psi)$, and $a,b\in\mathbb R$ holds.

Comment: A functional **is** a function. The only peculiarity is that a functional is defined on a set of  functions. A function can be defined on any set. It is just terminology.

Comment: For any continuous function $f: [a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ define the linear functional $I(f)=\int\limits_a^b f(t)dt$ which is an area. That's one example. There's many examples of linear functionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pose a dichotomy that is not so. One does not look at functionals as opposed to functions.

- First of all, a functional **is** a function.
- Second, you say that "functions evaluate points". That's not a good point of view. Typical calculus functions evaluate on *numbers*, as they usually evaluate as formulas. But it's very easy, even at the calculus level, to think of functions that evaluate on functions. For example, given a curve $r:t\longmapsto (x(t),y(x))$, $t\in[0,1]$, its *length* is the function $L(r)=\int_0^1\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\,dt$. So $L$ is a function that evaluates on functions.

Linear functionals are important because it is extremely common in mathematics for certain objects to form a *vector space*. And it's been noticed that to understand a vector space, in particular when they are infinite-dimensional, understanding of its *dual* is important, and often times helps prove results about the space. That's the core of Functional Analysis, and understanding of topological vectors spaces (Banach Spaces, Hilbert Spaces, Frechet Spaces, Bounded Linear Operators on a Banach Space, etc., etc., etc. ) comes together with understanding their duals.

Comment: You meant Linear functionals are important because they from a *vector space*?

Comment: No. $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: then I don't get what you mean in *the importance of Linear functionals*

Comment: Can you explain please

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you expect. If what I wrote in the last paragraph is not familiar to you, maybe you should tell us where you are coming from: why are you asking about linear functionals?

Comment: I don't see how this line *Linear functionals are important because it is extremely common in mathematics for certain objects to form a vector space.* explains the importance of linear functional, really.  It all comes because I started to read a book about Linear Operators